# Handling dependencies in SVN

Tags: java, svn

I'm working with a team that will soon be coding a bunch of Java apps as part of a larger project. We are planning to use SVN for our source code, but we will have dependencies on a number of other teams who are NOT using SVN. They will basically be coding a number of libraries (in the form of a .jar) that we will utilize in our apps.

I understand that we might be able to use svn:externals if everyone was on SVN, but that doesn't seem possible in the near future. For now we'll probably just get updated .jar files from them about once a week.

I'm still relatively new to SVN, so what is the proper procedure for handling this? Do we check their .jar into our repository? Or should we avoid having binaries in the SCM like that? We've also explored using dependency management via Maven...which seems like a good option for sharing binaries between the teams, but I'm not sure if we really want something that complex.

Comment: What's your current build solution? If it's ant-based, migration to Maven might be quite painful. In that case I would suggest ivy for tracking dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking in libraries, especially third party ( in your case I think you can call them third party ), into SVN ( or any SCM ) is not a big deal and you get so much gains from the simplicity of that. Caveat that with if the jars or libs being too huge and also change frequently, you might go for more complexity ( like Maven, Ivy etc.)

And SVN is good at handling binary files and their diffs.

Comment: Maybe a Maven that does nothing but collect together latest versions of libraries and then dumps them into SVN, with simplified, non-versioned filenames?

Comment: Thanks - this is mainly what I was wondering about. The libs are small, so this is probably the simplest route.

Answer (score 6):

I have found that dependency management is best done with a maven or ivy repository. Artifactory and Nexus have free versions. You can then manage them from your build script. [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) if you are using Ant, [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), or [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/). I prefer Gradle.

Comment: A binary repository manager is the best way to go (shameless plug: +1 for Artifactory); ad-hoc dependency management methods such as VCS or network-shares lack many important features (binary version management, fine-grained security, proxying and caching remote repositories, metadata and much more).

Comment: Thanks - since asking the question, I was able to actually get Maven up and running. It was tricky to get things configured just right, but I do see a lot of benefits when it works right. I'll have to play around with a few scenarios to see what's easiest for my team.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading about Vendor Branches: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html

Comment: Didn't know about this feature - probably a little more involved than what we need, but it's handy to know SVN has a method for this.

Answer (score 0):

If space is not an issue (on the server) I don't think is wrong to check in binaries or even the source code of your dependencies. It's easier for everyone, that way people can simply checkout and build without much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If the binaries are large, then I would definitely avoid checking them in to the repository.  My suggestion would be to store the latest version of the jars on a public share, then mount to that share and link it through the project file.  This mean only one person would have to update the binaries, instead of every machine, as long as the paths to the mounted store remained the same.

If they're not too large, then it's not a big deal to check them in to the repo.